# Propabibility for reaching a point within specified steps

Tags: probability, permutations, contest-math

*A particle moves in a sequence of unit steps. Each step along North, South, East or West with
equal probability. It starts at the origin, let p be the probability that it will reach (2, 2) in less than 7
steps, then p is equal to*

I know probability for each direction is $\frac{1}{4}$

And there are 4 ways to reach the point in 4 steps while no way to reach in 5 steps and some cases for 6 steps

I want to know if there is a generalised way of solving in case the coordinate given is large in  a way that I can't count each and every step